# Data driven Selenium tests

Tags: selenium, ui-testing, data-driven-tests

I have created a Selenium test that runs fine, but the application is still in development. is there a way to place all the element ids/cssSelector/Xpath in one excel sheet and then pass the ones i need to each methods.?

Comment: usually these are added in properties file.

Comment: This looks just like what i was looking for thanks. just neesed a little direction >> www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2014/05/creating-object-repository-using.html

Comment: @Shar Your link is not valid... The requested page has been moved

Comment: God :( it was working but yes the .properties file worked a charm. I have been told that it is hard to follow tho for non developers so am still looking do this from an excel

Comment: http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2014/05/creating-object-repository-using.html

Answer (score 1):

I did achieve this using an excel quite simply I used the following method:

```
    public void dataLocator() throws Exception{
          FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("dataSheets\\testing doc.xlsx"));

          //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
          XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

          //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
          XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Marketing Project");

          //Iterate through each rows one by one assigning cell value to variable
          account = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
          projectname = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(1).getStringCellValue() +timestamp;
          reqType = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(2).getStringCellValue() ;
          Language = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(3).getStringCellValue();
          assetType = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(4).getStringCellValue();
          needReview = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(5).getStringCellValue();
          reviewer = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(6).getStringCellValue() ;
          date = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(7).getDateCellValue();
          stringDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date);
          moreInfo = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(8).getStringCellValue();

            workbook.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime back I created a blog post that talks about using PageFactory, having the locators available in an external file such as JSON and then coupling both to work together. [Here's](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2016/06/27/pagefactory-page-objects-and-locators-from-an-external-file/) the link.

Please see if that helps.